# Changing pixel values of GDAL VRT

Tags: gdal, gdalbuildvrt

Is it possible to manipulate the pixel values of a GDAL VRT and, if so, how? The original data must remain unchanged.

I have a dataset which might be a bit rotated so that there are no data values on the edges. I use region growing to find that parts on the edge to not touch no data values in the actual area. I want to interpolate in the actual area in a next step. Sometimes I might have e.g. a very large dataset or ASCII data which can not be overwritten.

Comment: Which kind of manipulation do you mean? I have used on-the-fly filters and I suppose that applying LUT could be possible as well.

Comment: I edited my post to make more clear of what I need.